# Dual RC522 on Orange PI

Tags: python, gpio, orange-pi

My goal is to use dual RFID RC522 readers with Orange PI.
So far, I have managed to make only one working. (reading google, armbian and orange pi forums). Here is what I have done so far:

Hardware connection:

[single RC 522](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzfU6.jpg)

```
 MOSI ——————————> pin 19
 MISO ——————————-> pin 21
 SCLK ——————————-> pin 23
 SDA ——————————–> pin 24
 RST ———————————> pin 22
 IRQ ———————————-> NONE
```

Second reader uses shared pins, except SDA, it goes to pin 26 on orange PI

software:

Install python dev

```
 apt-get install python-dev
```

Install orangepi_PC_gpio_pyH3 Library

```
  git clone https://github.com/duxingkei33/orangepi_PC_gpio_pyH3.git

  cd orangepi_PC_gpio_pyH3

  python setup.py install
```

Install SPI-Py Library

```
git clone https://github.com/lthiery/SPI-Py.git

cd SPI-Py

 python setup.py install
```

Install MFRC522-python

```
 git clone https://github.com/rasplay/MFRC522-python.git
```

The tricky part is, MFRC522-python is made to work with RASPBERRY PI on orange pi, one guy offered a solution by modifying MFRC522.py

```
    #import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import pyA20.gpio as GPIO
import spi
import signal

class MFRC522:
  NRSTPD = 22

  MAX_LEN = 16

  PCD_IDLE       = 0x00
  PCD_AUTHENT    = 0x0E
  PCD_RECEIVE    = 0x08
  PCD_TRANSMIT   = 0x04
  PCD_TRANSCEIVE = 0x0C
  PCD_RESETPHASE = 0x0F
  PCD_CALCCRC    = 0x03

  PICC_REQIDL    = 0x26
  PICC_REQALL    = 0x52
  PICC_ANTICOLL  = 0x93
  PICC_SElECTTAG = 0x93
  PICC_AUTHENT1A = 0x60
  PICC_AUTHENT1B = 0x61
  PICC_READ      = 0x30
  PICC_WRITE     = 0xA0
  PICC_DECREMENT = 0xC0
  PICC_INCREMENT = 0xC1
  PICC_RESTORE   = 0xC2
  PICC_TRANSFER  = 0xB0
  PICC_HALT      = 0x50

  MI_OK       = 0
  MI_NOTAGERR = 1
  MI_ERR      = 2

  Reserved00     = 0x00
  CommandReg     = 0x01
  CommIEnReg     = 0x02
  DivlEnReg      = 0x03
  CommIrqReg     = 0x04
  DivIrqReg      = 0x05
  ErrorReg       = 0x06
  Status1Reg     = 0x07
  Status2Reg     = 0x08
  FIFODataReg    = 0x09
  FIFOLevelReg   = 0x0A
  WaterLevelReg  = 0x0B
  ControlReg     = 0x0C
  BitFramingReg  = 0x0D
  CollReg        = 0x0E
  Reserved01     = 0x0F

  Reserved10     = 0x10
  ModeReg        = 0x11
  TxModeReg      = 0x12
  RxModeReg      = 0x13
  TxControlReg   = 0x14
  TxAutoReg      = 0x15
  TxSelReg       = 0x16
  RxSelReg       = 0x17
  RxThresholdReg = 0x18
  DemodReg       = 0x19
  Reserved11     = 0x1A
  Reserved12     = 0x1B
  MifareReg      = 0x1C
  Reserved13     = 0x1D
  Reserved14     = 0x1E
  SerialSpeedReg = 0x1F

  Reserved20        = 0x20  
  CRCResultRegM     = 0x21
  CRCResultRegL     = 0x22
  Reserved21        = 0x23
  ModWidthReg       = 0x24
  Reserved22        = 0x25
  RFCfgReg          = 0x26
  GsNReg            = 0x27
  CWGsPReg          = 0x28
  ModGsPReg         = 0x29
  TModeReg          = 0x2A
  TPrescalerReg     = 0x2B
  TReloadRegH       = 0x2C
  TReloadRegL       = 0x2D
  TCounterValueRegH = 0x2E
  TCounterValueRegL = 0x2F

  Reserved30      = 0x30
  TestSel1Reg     = 0x31
  TestSel2Reg     = 0x32
  TestPinEnReg    = 0x33
  TestPinValueReg = 0x34
  TestBusReg      = 0x35
  AutoTestReg     = 0x36
  VersionReg      = 0x37
  AnalogTestReg   = 0x38
  TestDAC1Reg     = 0x39
  TestDAC2Reg     = 0x3A
  TestADCReg      = 0x3B
  Reserved31      = 0x3C
  Reserved32      = 0x3D
  Reserved33      = 0x3E
  Reserved34      = 0x3F

  serNum = []

  def __init__(self,spd=1000000):
    spi.openSPI(speed=spd)
#    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
#    GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)
#    GPIO.output(self.NRSTPD, 1)
    self.MFRC522_Init()

  def MFRC522_Reset(self):
    self.Write_MFRC522(self.CommandReg, self.PCD_RESETPHASE)

  def Write_MFRC522(self,addr,val):
    spi.transfer(((addr<<1)&0x7E,val))

  def Read_MFRC522(self,addr):
    val = spi.transfer((((addr<<1)&0x7E) | 0x80,0))
    return val[1]

  def SetBitMask(self, reg, mask):
    tmp = self.Read_MFRC522(reg)
    self.Write_MFRC522(reg, tmp | mask)

  def ClearBitMask(self, reg, mask):
    tmp = self.Read_MFRC522(reg);
    self.Write_MFRC522(reg, tmp & (~mask))

  def AntennaOn(self):
    temp = self.Read_MFRC522(self.TxControlReg)
    if(~(temp & 0x03)):
      self.SetBitMask(self.TxControlReg, 0x03)

  def AntennaOff(self):
    self.ClearBitMask(self.TxControlReg, 0x03)

  def MFRC522_ToCard(self,command,sendData):
    backData = []
    backLen = 0
    status = self.MI_ERR
    irqEn = 0x00
    waitIRq = 0x00
    lastBits = None
    n = 0
    i = 0

    if command == self.PCD_AUTHENT:
      irqEn = 0x12
      waitIRq = 0x10
    if command == self.PCD_TRANSCEIVE:
      irqEn = 0x77
      waitIRq = 0x30

    self.Write_MFRC522(self.CommIEnReg, irqEn|0x80)
    self.ClearBitMask(self.CommIrqReg, 0x80)
    self.SetBitMask(self.FIFOLevelReg, 0x80)

    self.Write_MFRC522(self.CommandReg, self.PCD_IDLE);  

    while(i<len(sendData)):
      self.Write_MFRC522(self.FIFODataReg, sendData[i])
      i = i+1

    self.Write_MFRC522(self.CommandReg, command)

    if command == self.PCD_TRANSCEIVE:
      self.SetBitMask(self.BitFramingReg, 0x80)

    i = 2000
    while True:
      n = self.Read_MFRC522(self.CommIrqReg)
      i = i - 1
      if ~((i!=0) and ~(n&0x01) and ~(n&waitIRq)):
        break

    self.ClearBitMask(self.BitFramingReg, 0x80)

    if i != 0:
      if (self.Read_MFRC522(self.ErrorReg) & 0x1B)==0x00:
        status = self.MI_OK

        if n & irqEn & 0x01:
          status = self.MI_NOTAGERR

        if command == self.PCD_TRANSCEIVE:
          n = self.Read_MFRC522(self.FIFOLevelReg)
          lastBits = self.Read_MFRC522(self.ControlReg) & 0x07
          if lastBits != 0:
            backLen = (n-1)*8 + lastBits
          else:
            backLen = n*8

          if n == 0:
            n = 1
          if n > self.MAX_LEN:
            n = self.MAX_LEN

          i = 0
          while i<n:
            backData.append(self.Read_MFRC522(self.FIFODataReg))
            i = i + 1;
      else:
        status = self.MI_ERR

    return (status,backData,backLen)


  def MFRC522_Request(self, reqMode):
    status = None
    backBits = None
    TagType = []

    self.Write_MFRC522(self.BitFramingReg, 0x07)

    TagType.append(reqMode);
    (status,backData,backBits) = self.MFRC522_ToCard(self.PCD_TRANSCEIVE, TagType)

    if ((status != self.MI_OK) | (backBits != 0x10)):
      status = self.MI_ERR

    return (status,backBits)


  def MFRC522_Anticoll(self):
    backData = []
    serNumCheck = 0

    serNum = []

    self.Write_MFRC522(self.BitFramingReg, 0x00)

    serNum.append(self.PICC_ANTICOLL)
    serNum.append(0x20)

    (status,backData,backBits) = self.MFRC522_ToCard(self.PCD_TRANSCEIVE,serNum)

    if(status == self.MI_OK):
      i = 0
      if len(backData)==5:
        while i<4:
          serNumCheck = serNumCheck ^ backData[i]
          i = i + 1
        if serNumCheck != backData[i]:
          status = self.MI_ERR
      else:
        status = self.MI_ERR

    return (status,backData)

  def CalulateCRC(self, pIndata):
    self.ClearBitMask(self.DivIrqReg, 0x04)
    self.SetBitMask(self.FIFOLevelReg, 0x80);
    i = 0
    while i<len(pIndata):
      self.Write_MFRC522(self.FIFODataReg, pIndata[i])
      i = i + 1
    self.Write_MFRC522(self.CommandReg, self.PCD_CALCCRC)
    i = 0xFF
    while True:
      n = self.Read_MFRC522(self.DivIrqReg)
      i = i - 1
      if not ((i != 0) and not (n&0x04)):
        break
    pOutData = []
    pOutData.append(self.Read_MFRC522(self.CRCResultRegL))
    pOutData.append(self.Read_MFRC522(self.CRCResultRegM))
    return pOutData

  def MFRC522_SelectTag(self, serNum):
    backData = []
    buf = []
    buf.append(self.PICC_SElECTTAG)
    buf.append(0x70)
    i = 0
    while i<5:
      buf.append(serNum[i])
      i = i + 1
    pOut = self.CalulateCRC(buf)
    buf.append(pOut[0])
    buf.append(pOut[1])
    (status, backData, backLen) = self.MFRC522_ToCard(self.PCD_TRANSCEIVE, buf)

    if (status == self.MI_OK) and (backLen == 0x18):
      print "Size: " + str(backData[0])
      return  backData[0]
    else:
      return 0

  def MFRC522_Auth(self, authMode, BlockAddr, Sectorkey, serNum):
    buff = []
    buff.append(authMode)
    buff.append(BlockAddr)
    i = 0
    while(i < len(Sectorkey)):
      buff.append(Sectorkey[i])
      i = i + 1
    i = 0
    while(i < len(serNum)):
      buff.append(serNum[i])
      i = i +1
    (status, backData, backLen) = self.MFRC522_ToCard(self.PCD_AUTHENT,buff)
    if not(status == self.MI_OK):
      print "AUTH ERROR!!"
    if not (self.Read_MFRC522(self.Status2Reg) & 0x08) != 0:
      print "AUTH ERROR(status2reg & 0x08) != 0"

    return status

  def MFRC522_Read(self, blockAddr):
    recvData = []
    recvData.append(self.PICC_READ)
    recvData.append(blockAddr)
    pOut = self.CalulateCRC(recvData)
    recvData.append(pOut[0])
    recvData.append(pOut[1])
    (status, backData, backLen) = self.MFRC522_ToCard(self.PCD_TRANSCEIVE, recvData)
    if not(status == self.MI_OK):
      print "Error while reading!"

    print "Got data size: "+str(backLen)
    i = 0
    if len(backData) == 16:
      print "Sector "+str(blockAddr)+" "+str(backData)

  def MFRC522_Write(self, blockAddr, writeData):
    buff = []
    buff.append(self.PICC_WRITE)
    buff.append(blockAddr)
    crc = self.CalulateCRC(buff)
    buff.append(crc[0])
    buff.append(crc[1])
    (status, backData, backLen) = self.MFRC522_ToCard(self.PCD_TRANSCEIVE, buff)
    if not(status == self.MI_OK) or not(backLen == 4) or not((backData[0] & 0x0F) == 0x0A):
      status = self.MI_ERR

    print str(backLen)+" backdata &0x0F == 0x0A "+str(backData[0]&0x0F)
    if status == self.MI_OK:
        i = 0
        buf = []
        while i < 16:
          buf.append(writeData[i])
          i = i + 1
        crc = self.CalulateCRC(buf)
        buf.append(crc[0])
        buf.append(crc[1])
        (status, backData, backLen) = self.MFRC522_ToCard(self.PCD_TRANSCEIVE,buf)
        if not(status == self.MI_OK) or not(backLen == 4) or not((backData[0] & 0x0F) == 0x0A):
          print "Error while writing"
        if status == self.MI_OK:
          print "Data writen"


  def MFRC522_Init(self):
#    GPIO.output(self.NRSTPD, 1)

    self.MFRC522_Reset();


    self.Write_MFRC522(self.TModeReg, 0x8D)
    self.Write_MFRC522(self.TPrescalerReg, 0x3E)
    self.Write_MFRC522(self.TReloadRegL, 30)
    self.Write_MFRC522(self.TReloadRegH, 0)

    self.Write_MFRC522(self.TxAutoReg, 0x40)
    self.Write_MFRC522(self.ModeReg, 0x3D)
    self.AntennaOn()

  def GPIO_CLEEN(self):
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

4 lines are commented (109 - 111, 357) and first line is replaced to use pyA20.gpio instead of RPi.GPIO.

After that, I run read.py and it works like a charm.

```
import MFRC522
import signal

continue_reading = True
MIFAREReader = MFRC522.MFRC522()

cardA = [5,74,28,185,234]
cardB = [83,164,247,164,164]
cardC = [20,38,121,207,132]

def end_read(signal, frame):
  global continue_reading
  continue_reading = False
  print "Ctrl+C captured, ending read."
  MIFAREReader.GPIO_CLEEN()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, end_read)

while continue_reading:
  (status,TagType) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Request(MIFAREReader.PICC_REQIDL)
  if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
    print "Card detected"
  (status,backData) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Anticoll()
  if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
    print "Card read UID: "+str(backData[0])+","+str(backData[1])+","+str(backData[2])+","+str(backData[3])+","+str(backData[4])
    if  backData == cardA:
      print "is Card A"
    elif backData == cardB:
      print "is Card B"
    elif backData == cardC:
      print "is Card C"
    else:
      print "wrong Card"
```

That is the way to use the reader on ORANGE PI PC. I googled and read further, in order to use second reader I need to modify exact same lines that I commented in order it to work. It controls RC522 with that SDA PIN, chooses from which reader to read the data. I try to uncomment any of them, but errors appear. Looks like those use specific RPi.GPIO functions. My python knowledge is very basic. I try to find where exactly are described pins that are used, and failed. Tried just to replace that pin 24 with 26 in order to read data from second readed. So far no success.

Comment: I am trying the same steps on Orange Pi Zero and even a single MFRC-522 is not working. I tried images armbian image 5.24 (Debian Jessie)/5.25(Ubuntu Xenial).  Did you enable something else apart from steps mentioned here?

Comment: sory for late answer, i did not, but cuz no success for second reader abandon the project, now half a year ago, tried again and fail to start even single rc522, (different opi board and armbian release), got no clue why, no errors displayed and no readings

Comment: Make it work, describbed how here.  https://forum.armbian.com/index.php?/topic/3103-dual-rc522-on-orange-pi-pc/#comment-28824

Comment: @Gailu (and any one else who found this like I did) I got MFRC522 working on the Orangepi Zero. These instructions don't work for a Zero. I go over all the details regarding pinout and you can download/install with one command. Check it out: https://github.com/BiTinerary/OrangePiZeroMFRC522

Comment: For those who this instruction did not work, on new versions of armbian there are 2 modules need to be blacklisted in order to work:  

blacklist pcf8591
blacklist bmp085, unloading them do not work, need to be blacklisted and system rebooted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have very similar setup and have had similar problems.

It seems I managed to solve them, just last night! :)

My project involves:

- Orange pi zero
- 12-13 RFID-RC522 modules (for now only 2)
- SPI communication
- since I will need lots of digital output pins I will use 12-13 shift register ICs (74HC595)

Approaches and problems:

1. connect together SCK, MISO and MOSI pins, pull RST high, control each SS line separately by modifying MFRC522 class. Didn't work, maybe my timings were off, should connect logic analyzer and see.
2. connect together SCK, MISO, MOSI AND SS pins, pull RST high, switch on/off Vcc or GND pins (power down all readers but one, read from that one, switch to next). Didn't work and presented very interesting situation. In some cases RFID module can read cards even with Vcc, or GND, or both pins DISCONNECTED!!! There is some significant leakage current from the signal pins. Here I tried demuxes, shift registers, line driver ICs, nothing worked.
3. Finally, approach that DOES work. Connect together SCK, MISO, MOSI AND SS pins, control RST pin. RST when pulled low powers down module. Pull it up to power-on. So, initially all RST pins are pulled low, then one-by-one are pulled high, small delay to allow module to boot up (I use 200ms), call MFRC522_Init() (not sure if necessary in each cycle, doesn't hurt I guess), perform read, pull RST low, switch to next module. Nice side effect of this approach is low power consumption: 2 powered-down modules draw 3.6mA, 1 on - 1 off draw 18mA.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

It was been a while, i had learn a little, made two RC522 readers to work on ESP8266, but same scenario can be used on ORANCE PI, in my previous attempt I was trying to make them work in separate SPI interface, now I use one interface and control them with SS (SDA) signal, when is send LOW on it, reader is active for communication. That way can be used more than one and control them that way. Hope that help to someone who seek an answers here :)